# String Operation to Split on Punctuation

Tags: python, strings

I've a function to split text on punctuation and leave the rest of the string (including whitespace in other items of the list):

```
import unicodedata

def split_on_punc(text):
    chars = list(text)
    i = 0
    start_new_word = True
    output = []
    while i < len(chars):
        char = chars[i]
        if is_punctuation(char):
            output.append([char])
            start_new_word = True
        else:
            if start_new_word:
                output.append([])
            start_new_word = False
            output[-1].append(char)
        i += 1
    ##print(output)
    return ["".join(x) for x in output]

def is_punctuation(char):
    return True if unicodedata.category(char).startswith("P") else False
```

E.g.

```
split_on_punctuation("This, this a sentence. with lotsa' puncts!?@ hahaha looo world")
```

[out]:

```
['This',
 ',',
 ' this a sentence',
 '.',
 ' with lotsa',
 "'",
 ' puncts',
 '!',
 '?',
 '@',
 ' hahaha looo world']
```

It looks like a very complicated way to check through each character and then keep track of whether it's a start of a new word or not.

I'm looking for improvements in speed and simplicity.

Answer (score 15):

Billy Mays here for the [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library!

It's API-compatible with the standard Python [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re) module. It's powered by open source, and it's safe for colored fabrics and carpets!

The `regex` library offers things like `\p{Punctuation}`, which is actually a shorthand form of `p{Punctuation=Yes}` which is really a shortening of `p{General_category=Punctuation}`.

If you can make a Unicode query, `regex` supports it. Identifiers, Categories, Blocks, Diacritical Marks - it even does Coptic!

It cleans! It brightens! It eliminates odors! All at the same time!

```
test_data = "This, this a sentence. with lotsa' puncts!?@ hahaha looo world"
print(f"Test data: '{test_data}'")

import regex

PUNCT_RE = regex.compile(r'(\p{Punctuation})')    

print(PUNCT_RE.split(test_data))
```

The output looks like:

```
Test data: 'This, this a sentence. with lotsa' puncts!?@ hahaha looo world'
['This', ',', ' this a sentence', '.', ' with lotsa', "'", ' puncts', '!', '', '?', '', '@', ' hahaha looo world']
```

`regex` converts your code from a whopping 21 lines to a 1-line method call-- a 2000% reduction! But you gotta call now!

Here's how to order:

```
pip install regex
```

Comment: Is `unicodedata.category(char).startswith("P")` the same as regex's `\p{Punctuation}`?

Comment: @alvas Yes, they both reflect the unicode-category of the underlying character.

Comment: Is the capturing group required in `(\p{Punctuation})`? If it isn't required, isn't it better to just do `\p{Punctuation}` instead? (aka: no capturing group).

Comment: "I used to have a problem, so I used a regular-expression, now I have two problems."

Comment: The capturing group is required, @IsmaelMiguel - otherwise the punctuation itself would be discarded in the split.

Comment: Also, if you have Python 3, they already included regex as `re`, for free!  What a deal!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: This is the OP's use case. He wants the punctuation as well as the non-punctuation. That's a documented behavior of re.split, that if you use capture groups the capture text is included in the result.

Comment: @AustinHastings I was asking because I didn't knew if it was required to capture the separator for it to be part of the result. But thinking about it, it would be pretty weird if the default behaviour was to include the separator, with no option to do *not* include it in the results. But thank you

Answer (score 9):

## Return Simplification

This

```
def is_punctuation(char):
    return True if unicodedata.category(char).startswith("P") else False
```

can be

```
def is_punctuation(char):
    return unicodedata.category(char).startswith("P")
```

Since `unicodedata.category(char).startswith("P")` evaluates to a boolean expression, you can return the expression.

## Type Hints

These function headers

```
def split_on_punc(text):
def is_punctuation(char):
```

can be this

```
def split_on_punc(text: str) -> list:
def is_punctuation(char: str) -> bool:
```

Type Hints allow you to show what types of parameters are supposed to be passed, and what types are returned by these functions.

## Docstrings

You should include a [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings) at the beginning of every function, class and module you write. This will allow you to describe what functions do what, and what modules contain what functions and their purpose.

Comment: I think that the `chr` type hint is not correct, but I won't know for sure until this is answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229400/is-there-a-pep484-type-hint-for-character

Comment: @Reinderien The [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) show that `unicodedata.category` takes a `chr`, from what I interpreted.

Comment: Those `chr` are variable names, not type hints.

Comment: `chr` is not a valid type.

Comment: @Reinderien That makes sense. Reading the comments on your stackoverflow post also point to the idea of using `str`. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: using `from typing import List` you can give even further type-hinting with `split_on_punc(text: str) -> List[str]` - to show the returned list will be filled with only `str` objects.

Answer (score 3):

### First things:

You can trim off a little just by making the loop tighter. Python does pretty cool "for" loops:

`for char in chars` will loop through every character in the list 'chars'. That means you don't need to deal with the variable 'i'. In fact, you don't even need to cast the input to a list called 'chars'. Python can iterate through a string as if it were a list. So your loop can be:

`for char in text`

By my count, that saves you four lines of code right there.

-

### Next: Use fewer cases:

As written, you've effectively got three relevant paths through the loop, for three possible cases:

1. The character is punctuation.
2. The character isn't punctuation, and it's the first character after punctuation
3. The character isn't punctuation, and it's not the first character after punctuation

The distinction between (2) and (3) doesn't depend on the character you're dealing with. It depends on the previous character, which is why you've had to use the "start_new_word" variable to carry information over from one iteration of the loop into the next. I think loops are easier to deal with if you don't have to carry information over like that. So I'd want to find a way to eliminate it.

You're effectively using "start_new_word" as a signal that tells you to do `output.append([])`, at the start of the next loop. But why wait until the next loop? If you replace the `start_new_word = true` instructions with `output.append([])` instructions, then you'll always have a clean 'word' sitting at the end of the output list, ready to accept characters. That way, whenever you have a non-punctuation character you just append it to `output[-1]`, and you don't have to worry about whether it's the first character.

Comment: One snag: if you have two punctuation characters in a row, then this method will put an empty word in between them. ```[ "text", "@", "", "?"]```. - After you add an 'if' statement to deal with that, the function ends up just as long as it was before. But I think it's still 'cleaner' that way, without having to carry information over between loops.

Comment: Also, you're working with lists of characters, and then converting them to strings at the end with a join method. You could just work directly with strings. 


Instead of ```output.append([])``` and ```output[-1].append(new_character)``` you can do ```output.append('')``` and ```output[-1] += new_character```

That saves you from having to do the .join at the end.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of function could be designated for an API and should be clear for every developer that would use it.

As you probably know , there is already a [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method in string object. This method doesn't return separators (as they are usually useless).

For example:

```
"this.is.codereview".split('.')
```

outputs:

```
['this', 'is', 'codereview']
```

The naming of `split_on_punc` could be modified to spotlight this difference, or at least be clarified with a docstring.

I'll advise you to use explicit name of category in `is_ponctuation` to avoid ambiguities and unwilled split if another Category starts with 'P'.

```
def is_punctuation(char):
    return unicodedata.category(char) == "Po"
```

This function (inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2136580/7281306)) does quite the trick if you doesn't need to be too strict on ponctuation separators.

```
import string
import re

def split_on_punc(text):
    return [
      token
      for token in re.split("\(W)", text)
      if token not in string.whitespace
    ]
```

It splits the string considering every non-alphanumeric character as ponctuation using [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) from re standard python library then removes whitespaces from list. It's a way far less precise than Austin answer.

Comment: Hey, good first answer, welcome on CodeReview :)

Comment: This did not work for me since the `if token` is executed only after the regex execution. And \(W) cannot be right either, it causes unbalanced brackets because of the escape sign. I changed it to `import string
import re

def split_on_punc3(s):
    return [
      token
      for token in re.split("(\W" + '|'.join(string.whitespace) + ")", s)
    ]` to check the speed, and then it is the fastest of all.